# how to move iTunes files from external and internal drives to a single drive?

Tags: itunes, macos

I'm trying to merge two different iTunes libraries.  The bigger one (on an external HD) is the default library, so I am trying to open the smaller one (on the internal HD) to export it.  However, as the first step of this I need to option+click and hold down option while iTunes is loading.  It then prompts me to enter the location of the library to open, and I select the location of the smaller directory.  However as soon as iTunes comes up it appears no different than when the default, larger library is loaded.  When I go to preferences it still says the location is the location of the larger library!

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I tried renaming the external library so iTunes couldn't find it, but it still showed up! When I tried exporting to see what would happen, I got a mixture of both internal and external paths in the resulting XML file.  I tried doing the same thing when not trying to open a different library and got the same result.  So it looks like somehow iTunes has files in both places, but I need to move everything into a single location (internally), so how can I do this?

To clarify, I have two iTunes folders, one on an external HD and one on the internal HD, and it appears that when I open iTunes it knows about both folders.  I only want one folder (on the internal drive) so that, for instance, if I disconnect the external HD things don't get confused or messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that somehow the internal iTunes got imported into the external one without changing the location of the files.  So I went to:

```
File > Library > Organize Library > Consolidate Files
```

which caused it to move the files into the external drive library.